# Angular Router route guard CanActivate always returns false

Tags: angular, angular-router, canactivate

I have used `CanActivate` to protect a page but it always returning false because of that I can not access the protected router. I tried many ways, but was not successful to fix the issue. I am new to angular and I am stuck in validating the condition  if (data.hasPermission == true).

Can any one please help me?

auth.service.ts

```js
//Checking user access
getUserAccess(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`api/${name}/useraccess`).pipe(
        map(
            (response: any) => {
                return response;
            },
        ),
    );
};


checkUserPermission() {
    this.getUserAccess(this.name).subscribe(data => {
        this.hasaccess = false;
        if (data.hasPermission == true) {
            this.hasaccess = true;
        } else {
             this.hasaccess = false;
        }
    });

    return this.hasaccess
}


isUserHasAccess(): boolean {
    return this.hasaccess
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isUserHasAccess()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

json data from API

```html
{"hasPermission":true}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a static value, you're not waiting for the async task to complete.

Look closely at the docs, `canActivate` can also return an `Observable` that resolves to `true` or `false`, this allows you to do async checks.

Try this instead:

```js
checkUserPermission() {
    return this.getUserAccess(this.name).pipe(map(data => data.hasPermission === true))
}
```

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.checkUserPermission();
}
```

The Angular `Router` will subscribe to that `Observable`, you don't have to. All you have to do is map it to a function that returns a boolean.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, can you help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424097/why-angular-guards-can-activate-always-returns-false